# Example of Levi-Civita derivative - differentiate velocity vector field of curve wrt to itself

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

I'm really struggling with calculating an example of the levi-civita derivative right now. I'm assuming a curve on a surface $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, then the levi-civita derivative of a vectorfield $Y$ along $M$ wrt to a vectorfield $X$ on $M$ is given by $\nabla_X Y := (D_X Y)_{tangential}$ where $D_X Y$ is the directional derivative. This directional derivative of a vector field wrt to another one is defined as follows: if $Y = y^k \partial_k$ then $D_X Y = \sum_k (X(y^k)) \partial_k$ - so we apply $X$ as a differential operator to the component functions $y^k$. This seems to make sense but I'm struggling with applying it.

Consider the parameterized curve $$\gamma(t) = (t², t³),$$ then we should be able to compute the levi-civita derivative of its velocity vector field along itself. If I'm not mistaken this should end up just being the second derivative $\gamma''$ of $\gamma$ wrt to $t$.

Here's my attempt and thinking:

So our manifold $M$ is given by $\gamma(\mathbb{R})$. The velocity vector field $V_p$ is defined as follows: given some point $p = (x,y) = (t^2,t^3)$ in $M$ we define $V_p := (2t, 3t^2) = \gamma'(t)$. From this point on I'm a bit unsure: so we have $V_p = 2t \partial_x + 3t^3 \partial_y$ (?), our component functions are $v^x(x,y) = 2t = 2 \sqrt[3]{y}$ and $v^y(x,y) = 3t^2 = 3 \sqrt[3]{y}^2$. We now want to apply $2t \partial_x + 3t³ \partial_y$ to these functions. We find:
$$V_p v^x(x,y) = 2t \cdot 0 + 3t^3 \cdot \frac{2}{3 \sqrt[3]{y}^2} = \frac{2 y}{\sqrt[3]{y}^2} = 2 \sqrt[3]{y}$$ and

$$V_p v^y(x,y) = 2t \cdot 0 + 3t^3 \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{y}} = \frac{6 y}{\sqrt[3]{y}} = 6 \sqrt[3]{y}^2.$$

So the derivative $D_{V_p} V (x,y) = (2 \sqrt[3]{y}, 6 \sqrt[3]{y}^2) = 2 \sqrt[3]{y} \partial_x + 6 \sqrt[3]{y}^2 \partial_y$ or expressed in terms of $t$ we have $D_{V_p} V (t) = (2t, 6t^2)$? And from that point on I'd have to find the tangential component?

This just seems all wrong and I'm confused - I thought this levi-civita derivative should in this case just end up being the second derivative of the curve wrt to $t$, so $y''(t) = (2, 6t)$ but I somehow have one $t$ too much? And when doing to projection things get even worse.

In case it helps: I'm working with Tu's *differential geometry* and *an introduction to smooth manifolds*.

Comment: If you want to use the ambiant Levi-Civita connection, you have to extend smoothly the vector field $V$ in a neighbourhood of the curve $\gamma$.

Comment: @Didier can you give me some pointers for where I could read up on that? I thought for submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^3$ the Levi-Civita connection would just be the projected directional derivative. Does this just hold for surfaces and for curves I have to do something else?

Comment: If you want to project the L-C derivative, it has to be defined. But the L-C connection takes vector fields tangent to the ambiant manifold as entries, not vector fields along submanifolds. Hence, you have to extend the vector field (at least locally on an open subset), apply the L-C derivative, then restrict to the submanifold and project. Luckily (and this is one of the most important Theorem in Riemannian geometry), this does not depend on the extension you choose!

Comment: Add to previous comment: indeed, in the euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$, the L-C connection is juste the usual differentiation